# Number of Vertices with $\mu$ Common Neighbor

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

$\mathcal{G}$ is a graph class. Each graph $G$ of $\mathcal{G}$ has the following properties-

1. $G$ is a $k$ (variable with respect to different graphs) regular graph of $n$ vertices. The vertex set  $V$ consists all $n$ vertices of $G$.
2. Each $G$ has a subset $B$ of  $V$ with  $\mu$ (variable with respect to different graphs) common neighbors ( for all graphs of class $\mathcal{G}$).
3. $|B| \leq c$ where  $c$ is a constant (for all graphs of class $\mathcal{G}$).

Does  graph class $\mathcal{G}$ exist?

For example, if we consider *Strongly Regular Graph*, then $c$ does not exist.

Is there anything in literature  related to this  problem?

Comment: $|B|$ is the number of vertices in subset $B$.